# select all passengers that landed in Palma de Mallorca or Barcelona but not both

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have to create a statement that fulfills the following requirement:

> Provide a list of all passengers who have landed either at the airport "Palma de Mallorca" or in "Barcelona". But by no means on both.

with this database:
[Flughafen-database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6prhd.png)

this is what i came up with:

```
select * 
from person
    join passagierliste using (personid)
    join flug using (flugid)
    join flughafen on flug.flughafen_destination=flughafen.flughafenid
where (flughafenid = 'Palma de Mallorca') xor (flughafenid = 'Barcelona')
;
```

but that throws the following error:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
> select *
> from person
> join passagierliste using (personid)
> join flug using (flugid)
> join flughafen on flug.flughafen_...
> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=933]
>
> Execution time: 0.03s
>
> 1 statement(s) failed.

**Update**

found an error but not the error (instead of flughafenid I should have used bezeichnung:

```
select * 
from person
    join passagierliste using (personid)
    join flug using (flugid)
    join flughafen on flug.flughafen_destination=flughafen.flughafenid
where (bezeichnung = 'Palma de Mallorca') xor (bezeichnung = 'Barcelona')
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the personid and count the distinct descriptions (bezeichnung) in the group. Because of the `WHERE` clause, you know that only descriptions of Mallorca or Barcelona are selected. That means if there's more than 1 distinct description per person, they've visited both. Use this (untested) as a CTE or subquery to get the relevant data from the `person` table.

```
select person.personid
from person
    join passagierliste using (personid)
    join flug using (flugid)
    join flughafen on flug.flughafen_destination=flughafen.flughafenid
where bezeichnung IN('Palma de Mallorca', 'Barcelona')
group by person.personid
having count(distinct bezeichnung) = 1
```

Comment: thanks i put this into a subselect to get the whole person